# How Iterate or remove MongoDb array list item using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, non-relational-database

I want to iterate Mongodb database Arraylist items(TRANSACTION list)  and remove  Arraylist specific(TRANSACTION List) item using pymongo ?

[image]

I create Mongo collection as above using python pymongo. I want to iterate array list item using pymongo and remove final item only in Arraylist?

Data insert query using Python pymongo

```
 # added new method  create block chain_structure
    def addCoinWiseTransaction(self, senz, coin, format_date):
        self.collection = self.db.block_chain
        coinValexists = self.collection.find({"_id": str(coin)}).count()
        print('coin exists : ', coinValexists)
        if (coinValexists > 0):
            print('coin hash exists')
            newTransaction = {"$push": {"TRANSACTION": {"SENDER": senz.attributes["#SENDER"],
                                                        "RECIVER": senz.attributes["#RECIVER"],
                                                        "T_NO_COIN": int(1),
                                                        "DATE": datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                                                        }}}
            self.collection.update({"_id": str(coin)}, newTransaction)
        else:
            flag = senz.attributes["#f"];
            print flag
            if (flag == "ccb"):
                print('new coin mined othir minner')
                root = {"_id": str(coin)
                    , "S_ID": int(senz.attributes["#S_ID"]), "S_PARA": senz.attributes["#S_PARA"],
                        "FORMAT_DATE": format_date,
                        "NO_COIN": int(1),
                        "TRANSACTION": [{"MINER": senz.attributes["#M_S_ID"],
                                         "RECIVER": senz.attributes["#RECIVER"],
                                         "T_NO_COIN": int(1),
                                         "DATE": datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                                         }
                                        ]
                        }
                self.collection.insert(root)
            else:
                print('new coin mined')
                root = {"_id": str(coin)
                    , "S_ID": int(senz.attributes["#S_ID"]), "S_PARA": senz.attributes["#S_PARA"],
                        "FORMAT_DATE": format_date,
                        "NO_COIN": int(1),
                        "TRANSACTION": [{"MINER": "M_1",
                                         "RECIVER": senz.sender,
                                         "T_NO_COIN": int(1),
                                         "DATE": datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                                         }
                                        ]
                        }
                self.collection.insert(root)

        return 'DONE'
```

Comment: It'd be better to include the query/output in that image as actual text in your question.

Comment: Do you wish to update for every document in your collection?

Comment: @chridam no, when i give some id, it is enough to update that tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the last entry, the general idea (as you have mentioned) is to iterate the array and grab the index of the last element as denoted by its `DATE` field, then update the collection by removing it using **[`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)**. So the crucial piece of data you need for this to work is the `DATE` value and the document's `_id`.

One approach you could take is to first use the aggregation framework to get this data. With this, you can run a pipeline where the first step if filtering the documents in the collection by using the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator which uses standard MongoDB queries.

The next stage after filtering the documents is to flatten the `TRANSACTION` array i.e. denormalise the documents in the list so that you can filter the final item i.e. get the last document by the `DATE` field. This is made possible with the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator, which for each input document, outputs n documents where n is the number of array elements and can be zero for an empty array.

After deconstructing the array, in order to get the last document, use the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator where you can regroup the flattened documents and in the process use the group [accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators) operators to obtain
the last `TRANSACTION` date by using the **[`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max)** operator applied to its embedded `DATE` field.

So in essence, run the following pipeline and use the results to update the collection. For example, you can run the following pipeline:

**mongo shell**

```
db.block_chain.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": coin_id } },
    { "$unwind": "$TRANSACTION" },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "last_transaction_date": { "$max": "$TRANSACTION.DATE" }
        }
    }
])
```

You can then get the document with the update data from this aggregate operation using the **[`toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/)** method or the aggregate cursor and update your collection:

```
var docs = db.block_chain.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": coin_id } },
    { "$unwind": "$TRANSACTION" },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE": { "$max": "$TRANSACTION.DATE" }
        }
    }
]).toArray()

db.block_chain.updateOne(
    { "_id": docs[0]._id },
    { 
        "$pull": { 
            "TRANSACTION": { 
                "DATE": docs[0]["LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE"] 
            } 
        } 
    }
)
```

---

**python**

```
def remove_last_transaction(self, coin):
    self.collection = self.db.block_chain

    pipe = [
        { "$match": { "_id": str(coin) } },
        { "$unwind": "$TRANSACTION" },
        { 
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "last_transaction_date": { "$max": "$TRANSACTION.DATE" }
            }
        }
    ]

    # run aggregate pipeline
    cursor = self.collection.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
    docs = list(cursor)

    # run update
    self.collection.update_one(
        { "_id": docs[0]["_id"] },
        { 
            "$pull": { 
                "TRANSACTION": { 
                    "DATE": docs[0]["LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE"] 
                } 
            } 
        }
    )
```

---

Alternatively, you can run a single aggregate operation that will also update your collection using the **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** pipeline which writes the results of the pipeline to the same collection:

> If the collection specified by the **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** operation already
>   exists, then upon completion of the aggregation, the [**`$out`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) stage atomically replaces the existing collection with the new results collection. The **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** operation does not
>   change any indexes that existed on the previous collection. If the
>   aggregation fails, the **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** operation makes no changes to
>   the pre-existing collection.

For example, you could run this pipeline:

**mongo shell**

```
db.block_chain.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": coin_id } },
    { "$unwind": "$TRANSACTION" },
    { "$sort": { "TRANSACTION.DATE": 1 } }
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "LAST_TRANSACTION": { "$last": "$TRANSACTION" },
            "FORMAT_DATE": { "$first": "$FORMAT_DATE" },
            "NO_COIN": { "$first": "$NO_COIN" },
            "S_ID": { "$first": "$S_ID" },
            "S_PARA": { "$first": "$S_PARA" },
            "TRANSACTION": { "$push": "$TRANSACTION" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "FORMAT_DATE": 1,
            "NO_COIN": 1,
            "S_ID": 1,
            "S_PARA": 1,
            "TRANSACTION": { 
                "$setDifference": ["$TRANSACTION", ["$LAST_TRANSACTION"]]
            }
        }
    },
    { "$out": "block_chain" }
])
```

---

**python**

```
def remove_last_transaction(self, coin):    
    self.db.block_chain.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "_id": str(coin) } },
        { "$unwind": "$TRANSACTION" },
        { "$sort": { "TRANSACTION.DATE": 1 } },
        { 
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "LAST_TRANSACTION": { "$last": "$TRANSACTION" },
                "FORMAT_DATE": { "$first": "$FORMAT_DATE" },
                "NO_COIN": { "$first": "$NO_COIN" },
                "S_ID": { "$first": "$S_ID" },
                "S_PARA": { "$first": "$S_PARA" },
                "TRANSACTION": { "$push": "$TRANSACTION" }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "FORMAT_DATE": 1,
                "NO_COIN": 1,
                "S_ID": 1,
                "S_PARA": 1,
                "TRANSACTION": { 
                    "$setDifference": ["$TRANSACTION", ["$LAST_TRANSACTION"]]
                }
            }
        },
        { "$out": "block_chain" }
    ])
```

Whilst this approach can be more efficient than the first, it requires knowledge of the existing fields first so in some cases the solution cannot be practical.

Comment: Thank you, I will code using python , and connet with mongo db using pymongo, is this python code?

Comment: No, this is code you can run on the server in mongo shell. The concepts are not that different though with the pymongo driver.

Comment: try second method , 1 come syntax error , but when i put comma (,) after, ' { "$sort": { "TRANSACTION.DATE": 1 } },' this line , error was gone,but when i run code it gave, this error .   {"$out": {"block_chain"}}
exceptions.TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' ?

Comment: 1 st solution also ,pass error, "   raise TypeError("pipeline must be a list")
exceptions.TypeError: pipeline must be a list" in "# run aggregate pipeline" line?

Comment: My bad, I've managed to fix the typos. Wrote this in a jiffy without proper testing so take note it may throw some errors but I think you are able to take some useful concepts from the answer, hopefully :)

Comment: @childam , i will try fix it.

Comment: @childam, i can get success from method 1.